# What are "concretors' nippers" for?

Tags: concrete, tools

I came across this tool called "concretors' nippers"

[image: http://www.knipex.com/fileadmin/site/knipex/scripts/mediando/images/KNIPEX/Produktfotos/web/zoom/99102504k.jpg]

I guess they are for some operations with concrete reinforcement, but can't find any details.

What operations is this tool for specifically? Where do I find more info?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what the orthodontist used to remove my braces.

Answer (score 8):

These are used to tie rebar wire around rebars - twisting the wire around the rebars, and then cutting the left over. Rebars are used prior to pouring the concrete to strengthen the concrete, hence the tool name.

They are also called "end-nippers", and are useful for cutting or grabbing things close to the 
surface, such as nails or the like. Finally, they can be used to cut tiles, however I have no experience with this function and can't comment on it.

See [this nice little PDF](http://www.rittbul.bg/files/knipex/15_CONCRETORS%20NIPPERS.pdf) that shows a picture of the two uses of this tool (no affiliation, just what Google came up with).

Comment: Those pictures show pretty thin wire being twisted. Is such huge leverage really necessary for that?

Comment: Yes, rebar tie wire is pretty thin. I think that this tool is a general purpose one - also used for cutting nails and tiles, so the leverage is used there.

Comment: If you've been wiring up rebar all day, you come to appreciate that leverage. So, no. Another nifty tool you'll come to appreciate is a hook twister.

Comment: Tile nippers usually leave a small gap in the cutting edge when completely closed. This leads me to believe they are for cutting and twisting wire but not for tile.

Comment: This was the only tool I had that could cut the twisted wire for my Dog run I installed the other day.  Thanks, did not know what it was called.